# Script measuring bounding box size of selected objects, and copying those values into the objects' viewport colors (XYZ = RGB)?

Tags: scripting, objects, transforms, procedural, shader-nodes

I'd like to find a simple scripted way how to:

1. measure the bounding box(es) of a selected object(s)
2. take the XYZ values, and convert them into 0 to 1 numbers with the correct ratio
3. Feed these three values to the RGB setting of the object viewport color

I need this to correct the generated texture space for my procedural material (the object color is fed into the correcting mapping node, so RGB = XYZ). Object mapping would fix that, but the textures are sliding when the animation is done with an armature, so this workaround is great. The only disadvantage is the need to set all the RGB values by hand, which is not exact and takes a lot of time. Automating this would be great and it seems like a 5-minute task for a pro, so I'm looking for some community help :D

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In code, the bounding box returns 8 vertices, each one has a X,Y,Z coordinate, I assume you are looking for the median point of the box?

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm looking for the edge lengths of an imaginary block created out of these points, and their comparison.

If the 8 vertices are numbered the same way as in the basic cube mesh, then it should be like this:

X lenght = distance of the points 0 and 4
Y lenght = distance of the points 0 and 2
Z lenght = distance of the points 0 and 1

These three numbers would be for example 4, 2, and 1, then they should be converted to 1, .5 and .25 (to cover the full range of 0-1), and applied to the viewport color's RGB.